# How to modify CAS 5.x to use rest api to check user's loginname and password

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas

I am trying to use CAS 5.x, but don't known how to make the CAS to use the rest api to do the user identity work. e.g. CAS calling a 'user service' which will offer the api to check the user login name and password.

Seems CAS 5.x is quite different from the 3.x version.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?
https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/installation/Rest-Authentication.html

This allows the CAS server to reach to a remote REST endpoint via a POST for verification of credentials. Credentials are passed via an Authorization header whose value is Basic XYZ where XYZ is a Base64 encoded version of the credentials.

The response that is returned must be accompanied by a 200 status code where the body should contain id and attributes fields, the latter being optional, which represent the authenticated principal for CAS